# recommendation for migrating edited site map between environments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am in a development environment and have edited the site map using the following steps
    -

- creating an unmanaged solution
- added existing site map
- exported solution as ummanaged
- edited customisations.xml
- zipped up files and give same zip file name as exported solution
- reimported solution into same environment

this has worked ok, but how should i now migrate these changes to a different environment namely training and ultimately live environment. Do i export as a managed solution and import into train/live or do i customise the site map on ea`ch environment

thanks for any advice

richard

Answer (score 0):

As you should not modify the sitemap in your production/training organization I would recommend to export it as managed solution. With the managed approach it's possible to update the solution later on or to revert the changes by deinstalling it.

An unmanaged solution is more like a logical container. If it's imported into an organization, the changes are not reversible.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is managed or unmanaged, the point is that the site map is included in the solution